# How to Apply style in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I Have a Repeater, and total three column are available `name` `dob` and `age`,
 but I want to Replace `today date(17 Aug 2018)` with `-` in the repeater. Is it possible?

Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblPatientList" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                <span><%#Eval("GFname") %></span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
               <span>
            <%#Eval("dob1").ToString() = '17 Aug 2018' ?  '-' %>
                    <%#Eval("dob") %></span>
            </td>
             <td class="text-center">
                <span><%#Eval("Age") %></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

From @Suprabhat comment there should be an answer not comment as like this:

```
Eval("dob1") != null ? (Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dob1").ToString()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy") == "17 Aug 2018" ? "-" : Eval("dob1").ToString()) : "-"
```

Replace above line with your line of code:

```
<%#Eval("dob1").ToString() = '17 Aug 2018' ?  '-' %> <%#Eval("dob") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is proper way to replace **date to '-'**

```
 <%# Eval("dob1").ToString() == "17 Aug 2018" ?  "-" : "Eval("dob1")" %>
```